# Revoke Create on public Schema from user - is not working in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am using `postgresql -8.4.20` which is a back-end for JON server and login with username `rhqadmin` and connected to database `rhq`.

After connecting It is redirecting me to public schema by default.
Now I don't want to allow this user `rhqadmin` to create tables in public Schema.

So I am revoking the Create privilege on public schema by using following command:-

```
Revoke Create ON SCHEMA public FROM rhqadmin;
```

Then it is giving me warning -

> "no privileges could be revoked for "public".

When I login with super user `postgres` and from there I revoke 'CREATE' privilege on public Schema for user `rhqadmin` then it is not giving any warning and successfully revoked then I logged in with user `rhqadmin` and try to create table in public schema and again it is allowing me to Create table even after revoking the create privilege from super user.

Please tell me why revoke privilege is not working for public Schema or I am doing any mistake.

Regards, 
Avinash

Answer (score 18):

Your problem is that the `CREATE` privilege is not granted to `rhqadmin`, but to the special role `PUBLIC` to which everybody belongs by default.

Since privileges in PostgreSQL are additive, there is no way to explicitly forbid something to only a single user if it is allowed to everybody.

The solution is probably:

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

Comment: No, so far I have tried this above solution but it is also not working for public schema . I mean it should not allow me to create tables in public schema. but still I can create tables.

Comment: Run `\dn+ public` in `psql` and add the result to the question, then I can figure out what is going on. Has your user any roles (groups) granted?

Comment: Thanks Laurenz(Sorry for the late reply) but Its working now. See I was doing a mistake that I am executing this Revoke command inside the postgres db with postgres user. so if i want to revoke for rhqadmin user which is connecting to rhq db,then I have to connect as postgres user with rhq db and now gave the command and its working. :-)